# Flutter connectivity false callback

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Im using connectivity package to track users connection changes. The idea is to pop up a warning page for connection loss when the ConnectivityResult is none (aka wifi and mobile is disconnected). But instead i get these results :
If the wifi is connected and you disconnect it, 50% of the time the warning pops up.
If you are on mobile and turn it off, the connectivity returns that user is still on ConnectivityResult.mobile not ConnectivityResult.none.

Tried to make a doublecheck with pinging google, but even that doesnt work as smooth as i expected it to be.

My code :
I have created seperated file with functions :

```
void trackNetworkStatus(BuildContext ctx) {
  //check in case state is just opened
  pingGoogle(ctx);

  //add network listener
  Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
    print("Network changed to $result");
    //if user lost connection
    if (result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      openNoInternetScreen(ctx);
    }else{
      //if user has connection, doublecheck
      //mobile network is tricky on android
      pingGoogle(ctx);
    }
  });
}

Future<void> pingGoogle(BuildContext ctx) async {
  try {
    //ping internet page
    final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');

    //if ping is successful
    if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
      print('connected');
    }else{
      print('not connected');
      openNoInternetScreen(ctx);
    }
  } on SocketException catch (_) {
    print('not connected');
    openNoInternetScreen(ctx);
  }
}

void openNoInternetScreen(BuildContext ctx) {
  Navigator.push(
    ctx,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => noInternetPage()),
  );
}
```

because i am calling them on every apps init like this :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //listen to netwoek changes
    trackNetworkStatus(context);
  }
```

which leads to problem that sometimes warning page pops up twice because, as i believe, the previous listener has not been stopped, but i can figure out how to fix it. The question is why connectivity package returns false callback on mobile. Ive tested on virtual Android API 23 and Samsung S9+, both share same results.

Comment: I just ran connectivitys package example code and i got the same story there - when disconnecting from mobile network, it still says that i have mobile network status. Once i turn on and off wifi, it works correctly, unlike the mobile newtork. Weird. Is this a packages bug ?

Answer (score 0):

I gave my app to couple early testers and everything turned out just fine for them, even if some of them own Samsung devices too. Looks like there is no problem at all with the connectivity package, some of Samsung phones just act weird as they shouldnt. Looks like there will always be a black sheep in the whole community, sadly thats me and im the developer with this buggy device.

Havent found the fix for my device, but looks like the package is safe to go for the most of the devices in market.

The phone model, that is acting strange : SM-G965F.